# Error running $ juju quickstart

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

Error running $ juju quickstart. I doubt there is some problem with maas installation but can't find any.

```
juju quickstart v2.2.4
    ssh-agent has been started.
    To interact with Juju or quickstart again after quickstart
    finishes, please run the following in a terminal to start ssh-agent:
      eval `ssh-agent`

    bootstrapping the maas environment
    juju-quickstart: error: Bootstrapping environment "maas"
    Starting new instance for initial state server
    Launching instance
    WARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
     - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-8a3bd444-4d91-11e6-aa49-ecb1d76ea468/
    Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
    Waiting for address
    Attempting to connect to 10.1.1.151:22
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
    Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
    It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
    The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
    37:0d:79:f3:09:03:b0:1c:98:ae:7e:eb:81:c2:17:83.
    Please contact your system administrator.
    Add correct host key in /home/student/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
    Offending ECDSA key in /home/student/.ssh/known_hosts:1
      remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/student/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 10.1.1.151
    Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
    bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_IN)
    /bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_IN)
    Logging to /var/log/cloud-init-output.log on remote host
    Running apt-get update
    Running apt-get upgrade
    Installing package: curl
    Installing package: cpu-checker
    Installing package: bridge-utils
    Installing package: rsyslog-gnutls
    Installing package: cloud-utils
    Installing package: cloud-image-utils
    Installing package: tmux
    Fetching tools: curl -sSfw 'tools from %{url_effective} downloaded: HTTP %{http_code}; time %{time_total}s; size %{size_download} bytes; speed %{speed_download} bytes/s ' --retry 10 -o $bin/tools.tar.gz <[https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.5/juju-1.25.5-trusty-amd64.tgz]>
    Write failed: Broken pipe
    ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 255
```

How can I fix the problem the problem?